# Boxplot visualization

Tags: python, data-visualization, boxplot

So I have to do this boxplot, and I want to limit the variables from a column in a dataset, and the problem I am having is that I don't know how to do that. [this is what I have for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGGAj.png), I want to pick the top ten nationalities that are in the column, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by top ten? top ten in median height? or maximum height?

Comment: I wanted the top ten repeated nationalities. So I can plot them against the height

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work for a dataframe called `df` with a "Nationality" column called `Nationality`:

```
import collections

counts = collections.Counter(df.Nationality)
top10countries = [elem for elem, _ in counts.most_common(10)]

df_top10 = df[df['Nationality'].isin(top10countries)]
```

and then use `df_top10` to make boxplots.

Comment: YESS. THIS WORKED. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: glad to help. if you found it useful, could you marked it solved?